# Webview not working with minifyEnabled set to true

Tags: android, kotlin

I have already tried adding following rules to the pro guard but nothing has worked yet

```
-keep class my_package_name.adm.** {*;}
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface <methods>;
}
-keepattributes JavascriptInterface
-keep public class package_path$JavaScriptInterface
-keep public class * implements package_pat$JavaScriptInterface
-keepclassmembers class package_pat$JavaScriptInterface {
    <methods>;
}

-keepattributes *Annotation*
```

Comment: can you share the more detail like any errors in ```Logcat```.

Comment: as its a prod version I don't have any logs

Comment: try using this ```-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
   public *;
}```

Comment: sorry haven't mentioned here but already tried that but its not working

Comment: -keepclassmembers class package_pat$JavaScriptInterface {
    public *;
} right ?

Comment: No, That's not. Try it on another project with single-page webview app. It might help

Comment: So I needed to add one missing File that we used in the URL creation into the proguard. Thanks for you help @Chirag Thummar